# Deleting ALL ActiveRecord Join associations through a rails form. (Adding and modifying works fine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I think I've narrowed down how to create/modify associations through forms. However, I cannot seem to remove **all** associations through this same method, because the submitted parameters include a blank array (nothing is selected in the form). When the array is empty, Rails does **nothing** instead of deleting all the association records.

So here's an example of my application. Here are two models:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :classes
end
```

and

```
#app/models/class.rb
class Class < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

Now let's say my form is for `Student`:

```
  <%= form_with(model: @student, local: true) do |form| %>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover student-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><%= check_box_tag "student_header_checkbox", 0, false %></th>
            <th>Class Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @classes.each do |class| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "student[class_ids][]", class.id, is_student_part_of_class(class) %></td>
            <td><%= class.name %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
        <i class='fa fa-save'></i> Save changes
      </button>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Now in my `Student` controller, I am permitting `class_ids` by doing this at the bottom:

```
#app/controllers/students.rb
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:class_ids => [])
end
```

Ok, so all is well. When the user selects many classes, the classes are passed to the `Student` controller as an array. If there are classes selected, then an appropriate association record is created, and now that student "has_and_belongs_to_many" classes.

**Now here's the problem**

Let's say you have multiple classes added to this student, **if you delete all the classes**, then there is basically no array that gets passed to the controller; therefore, the controller does not delete **all** classes associated with this student.

If you modify the selection by, let's say, adding a class, removing a class, etc. **anything but deselecting ALL classes**, then everything works just fine.

Does rails not handle deleting all association records automatically like this? Or am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: This may not answer your actual question, but you should avoid the words `Class` or `class` in Ruby. `class` is a keyword, and `Class` is a "first-class"-class in Ruby core (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Class.html).

Comment: I agree and thank you. My rails app is actually using a different name. I built this example just for the sake of getting help, but I really appreciate it though!

Answer (score 0):

I just made an additional function in the controller to solve this problem as a temporary workaround for now:

```
# called after update
def delete_all_associations_if_empty
   classes = student_params[:classes]
   if classes.nil? or classes.empty?
      @student.classes = []
   end
end
```